# import mongoose schema into another schema file makes the imported schema undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

File structure:

```
│   resolvers.js
│   schema.js
│
└───schemas
        matchesSchema.js
        playersSchema.js
        teamsSchema.js
        tournamentsSchema.js
```

So I have 4 schema's and I want to use the other schema's in the all my schema's but when I import it I get an error:

```
C:\Users\phara0h\Dropbox\esports-scores.com\nodeTest\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:425
      throw new TypeError('Invalid value for schema Array path `' + prefix + key + '`');
      ^

TypeError: Invalid value for schema Array path `matches`
    at Schema.add (C:\Users\phara0h\Dropbox\esports-scores.com\nodeTest\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:425:13)
    at new Schema (C:\Users\phara0h\Dropbox\esports-scores.com\nodeTest\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:99:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:/Users/phara0h/Dropbox/esports-scores.com/nodeTest/src/schemas/tournamentsSchema.js:8:34)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at loader (C:\Users\phara0h\Dropbox\esports-scores.com\nodeTest\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\Users\phara0h\Dropbox\esports-scores.com\nodeTest\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:/Users/phara0h/Dropbox/esports-scores.com/nodeTest/src/schemas/teamsSchema.js:5:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at loader (C:\Users\phara0h\Dropbox\esports-scores.com\nodeTest\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\Users\phara0h\Dropbox\esports-scores.com\nodeTest\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
```

When I `console.log` the imported variable they are undefined.

playersSchema.js:

```js
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';
import timestamps from 'mongoose-timestamp';
import { MatchesSchema } from './matchesSchema';
import { TeamsSchema } from './teamsSchema';
import { TournamentsSchema } from './tournamentsSchema';

// Mongoose Schema definition
export const PlayersSchema = new Schema({
    active: Boolean,
    captain: {type: Boolean, default: false},
    activeTeam: String,
    birthDate: Date,
    country: String,
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    nickName: String,
    matches: [MatchesSchema],
    picture: String,
    position: String,
    steamId: String,
    twitch: String,
    teams: [TeamsSchema],
    tournaments: [TournamentsSchema]
});
PlayersSchema.plugin(timestamps);
PlayersSchema.index({ activeTeam: 'text', country: 'text', firstName:     'text', lastName: 'text', nickName: 'text' });
export const PlayerDB = mongoose.model( 'Players', PlayersSchema );
```

matchesSchema.js:

```js
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';
import timestamps from 'mongoose-timestamp';
import { PlayersSchema } from './playersSchema';
import { TeamsSchema } from './teamsSchema';
import { TournamentsSchema } from './tournamentsSchema';

// Mongoose Schema definition
export const MatchesSchema = new Schema({
    dateUTC: String,
    ended: Boolean,
    lenght: String,
    matchDetails: Schema.Types.Mixed,
    matchId: Number,
    player: [PlayersSchema],
    teams: [TeamsSchema],
    tournament: {type: String, ref: TournamentsSchema },
    winner: String
});
MatchesSchema.plugin(timestamps);

export const MatchesDB = mongoose.model( 'Matches', MatchesSchema );
```

teamsSchema.js

```js
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';
import timestamps from 'mongoose-timestamp';
import { PlayersSchema } from './playersSchema';
import { MatchesSchema } from './matchesSchema';
import { TournamentsSchema } from './tournamentsSchema';

// Mongoose Schema definition
export const TeamsSchema = new Schema({
    country: String,
    teamTag: String,
    logo: String,
    matches: [MatchesSchema],
    name: String,
    players: [PlayersSchema],
    steamId: String,
    url: String,
    tournaments: [TournamentsSchema]
});
TeamsSchema.plugin(timestamps);
TeamsSchema.index({ teamTag: 'text', country: 'text', name: 'text' });
export const TeamsDB = mongoose.model( 'Teams', TeamsSchema );
```

tournamentsSchema.js

```js
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';
import timestamps from 'mongoose-timestamp';
import { PlayersSchema } from './playersSchema';
import { MatchesSchema } from './matchesSchema';
import { TeamsSchema } from './teamsSchema';

// Mongoose Schema definition
export const TournamentsSchema = new Schema({
    description: String,
    endDate: String,
    itemdef: Number,
    leagueid: Number,
    matches: [MatchesSchema], //<--- this causes the error
    name: String,
    organizer: String,
    production: String,
    prizepool: String,
    players: [PlayersSchema],
    results: String,
    startDate: String,
    teams: [TeamsSchema],
    tournamentUrl: String
});
TournamentsSchema.plugin(timestamps);
TournamentsSchema.index({ description: 'text', name: 'text', organizer : 'text' });
export const TournamentsDB = mongoose.model( 'Tournaments', TournamentsSchema );
```

Yes I could put them all in one file but since they all use each other but on the page lower schemes can't be included in to the above ones.

Thanx in advanced

Comment: It's checking in the wrong directory `nodeTest\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js`, notice the 1st line of the error. I'm sure your schemas are in a different directory... Just change the import line from `./playersSchema` to properly point to the correct directory/path

Comment: @Searching added the file structure, as you can see they are all located in the same directory

Comment: So yup the import statement should be something like `/schemas/playerschema`, and similar.

Comment: @Searching I think you're misunderstanding me these are the files I got the issue with: they are all located in the same folder.
`schema/matchesSchema.js`, `schema/playersSchema.js`, `schema/matchesSchema.js`, `schema/teamsSchema.js` and `schema/tournamentsSchema.js`

So I want to include all the above mentioned files in each other, and they are all located in the same folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution what is more a work around:
removed all the inclusions of the other schema's and made them

```
Schema.Types.Mixed
```

In the end I didn't need to do this since I made a graphQL server and I realized that GraphQL handled the output/input in a manner I wanted without having to define it in Mongoose.

Answer (score 8):

All is good, but it seems that we need to explicitly ask for the schema part of the object.

Instead of `player: [PlayersSchema]`,

try `player: [PlayersSchema.schema]`

Comment: That's not it, it's an issue that the the schema's are not yet defined when I'm trying to include them. But I ended up solving it in an other way.