# How to import one mongoose schema to another?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm making a node app to consume json API and I'd like to separate parts of `User` schema into separate files because there are many fields in `Profile` and separating files keeps things cleaner:

So basically instead of

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true }, 
    profile: { 
      gender: {
       type: String,
       required: true
       },
      age: {
        type: Number
      },
      //many more profile fields come here

    }
});
```

I do this:

`models/Profile.js` is:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const profileSchema = new Schema({
      gender: {
      type: String,
      required: true
      },
      age: {
        type: Number
      }
      //the rest of profile fields
});

module.exports = Profile = mongoose.model('profile', profileSchema);
```

And the `models/User.js` is:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const Profile = require('./Profile');

const userSchema = new Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true }, 
    profile: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Profile'},
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('users', userSchema);
```

The data for `User` and `Profile` are posted in the same json post.

However when node tries to save the object I get this error:

```
(node:4176) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: users validation failed: profile: Cast to ObjectID failed for value "{ gender: 'male'...
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try : `ref: 'Match._id'`

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT. Still  I get the the same error. Please provide a complete answer.

Comment: The error is about Object Id. The Id you are passing for 'match' key is not object Id. You can use mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id); If it's different error then please share your create document code.

Comment: @parth not sure what you mean. please elaborate with code.

Comment: match: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'match'}. This match key requires object id. So if you're passing string then it will give you this error. Check regEx for this too. => value.match(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/)

Comment: @parth please give me a complete answer by fixing my code.  I don't know how to apply your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can define it like this:

/Match.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const matchSchema = new Schema({
      gender: {
      type: String,
      required: true
      },
      age: {
        type: Number
      }
});

export const mongooseMatch = mongoose.model('match', matchSchema);
```

/User.js:

```
import mongooseMatch from './Match.js';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const Match = require('./Match');

const userSchema = new Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true }, 
    match: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Match'},
});

export const matchUser = userSchema.discriminator('matchUser', mongooseMatch);
```

Answer (score 1):

Match Model

```
// models/Match.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const matchSchema = new Schema({
      gender: {
      type: String,
      required: true
      },
      age: {
        type: Number
      }
});
module.exports = Match = mongoose.model('match', matchSchema);
```

User Model

```
// models/User.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true }, 
    match: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'match'},
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model('users', userSchema);
```

Then in your request add following code.

```
const User = require('../model/user');
const Match = require('../model/macth');

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {

    let newMatch = new Match({ gender: 'male'});
    newMatch.save().then(matchData => {
        console.log(matchData);
        let newUser = new User({ match: matchData._id, username: 'abc', password: '123456'});
        newUser.save().then(userData => {
            console.log(userData);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

});
```

Now Log out your result.

Comment: `match` has no _id. match is part of `user` json

Comment: Please check the documentation for this. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html

Comment: the docs does not answer my use case. Please have a look at my updated question. I tried to make it more explicit.

Comment: Use this Schema type. Schema.Types.Mixed. Ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43502870/import-mongoose-schema-into-another-schema-file-makes-the-imported-schema-undefi

Comment: Nice explanation. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you create your model like

```
module.exports = Match = mongoose.model('match', matchSchema);
```

then you have to `ref` to it with same name as first argument, so instead of `ref: 'Match'` should be ref: `match`.

Then if you want to create new document you should do it like

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Match = require("./Match");
const User = require("./User");
...
const m = await Match.create({
    gender: "male"
});

const u = await User.create({
  username: 'user',
  password: 'password',
  match: m
});
```

And if you query it later e.g

```
console.log(await User.find({}).populate("match"));
```

you should get something like

```
[ { _id: 5bf672dafa31b730d59cf1b4,
username: 'user',
password: 'password',
match: { _id: 5bf672dafa31b730d59cf1b3, gender: 'Male', __v: 0 },
__v: 0 } ]
```

I hope that helped

...

Edit

If you getting all the data from one JSON you still have to somehow pass `ObjectId` as a parameter for your `User` model. And it has to be existing `Match` to make possible to populate query later.

E.g

```
const user = req.body; // user data passed
const match = user.match;
const savedMatch = await Match.create(match);
user.match = savedMatch;
const savedUser = await User.create(user);
```

Comment: Well I'm working with a json API and the data for `match` and `user` come together in the same json post. So  I cannot hardcode the `match` value as you did. Please adjust your answer to my specific scenario.

Comment: I adjusted, you can also quety your db instead of creating new `match` if that's your case

Comment: There should be a better way. `match` is parts of the `user` document so I can't see why I should save them separately.